# Factorizing elements of a group into a product of generators.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

$$
s = (1\ 2) \\
t = (1\ 2\ 3\ ...\ n)
$$

Given the Symmetric Group $S_n$ generated by $s$ and $t$, is there a way to quickly factor an element $g \in S_n$ into a minimal product of positive powers of the generators $s$ and $t$?

A product is minimal if it has the lowest sum of the powers of its factors. For example: $s^3t$ has a sum of powers of $4$ and it's not minimal because there is an equivalent product $st$ whose sum of powers is $2$.

Currently, the way to do it exhaustively (not ideal) is to enumerate strings from the presentation and return the one whose product is $g$. I'd like a faster method if there is one, or a proof that there isn't one.

Comment: That presentation is *not* $\;S_n$' s but a rather pretty huge (infinite, in fact) group: the direct product $\;C_2*C_n\;$ .

Comment: @Timbuc There are some relations missing, but they're different for each $n$. You're right. However, I provided the values of the generators $s$ and $t$ such that it would not be an infinite group. (The proof for why those generators actually generate $S_n$ is another can of worms I'd have to open another time, if it's not immediately clear.) If you have a better way write the premise for the question, please suggest an edit.

Comment: @Ax The group which presentation you wrote is what I wrote in my past comment. Without getting into the relations, which can be messy (and perhaps seeing $\;S_n\;$ as a Coxeter group = generated only by elements of order two makes it easier), you could simply say that $\;S_n\;$ is generated by the cycles $\;(12)\,,\,\,(1\,2\,\ldots n)\;$ .

Comment: @Timbuc I've removed the incorrect presentation and am just stating its generation. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: @Ax Any time...and I've noticed now my first comment has an ugly mistake: it must say "the **free** product $\;C_2*C_n\;$", of course.

Comment: Either way, the way I had written the presentation allowed for elements to be of the form $(st)^x$ without bounds on $x$, which is enough to say that it presented an infinite group.

Comment: Am I right in thinking you don't want powers of the inverse of $t$ to appear in the presentation of elements?

Comment: You can improve the exhaustive search method by making use of other relations between the generators to eliminate repetitions, and there are ways of producing fast implementations using finite state automata to enumerate words. But I would guess that, in the end, there is nothing faster than "intelligent" exhaustive search. This problem is notroiously difficult - think of the Rubik cube problem! I don't think there is any chance at all of proving there is no faster method - that's probably as hard as proving $P \ne NP$.

Comment: @user24142 he said "positive powers".

Comment: I'm writing some code to test a hypothesis at the moment, and I'm wondering if anyone else has some output. For instance, the following list is the number of elements of $S_8$ that can be represented with 0, 1 etc generators. [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 54, 86, 133, 195, 275, 379, 514, 685, 901, 1170, 1492, 1850, 2217, 2586, 2947, 3276, 3534, 3649, 3589, 3343, 2865, 2167, 1358, 688, 239, 31, 9, 1]. Can anyone else verify if this is correct or in error? The worst element is $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\ 3 & 1 & 8 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 2 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 0):

There is a general method (i.e., one that works for any finite group and generating set) which is faster than exhaustion, but which requires a lot of storage space.

To find a factorization of a given length, exhaustion over products of roughly half the length is used.  The key fact is that if $g$ is a product of length $m$, and $k=\lfloor m/2\rfloor$ and $\ell=m-k$, then $gA^{-1}\cap B\neq\emptyset$ and conversely, where $A$ is the set of products of length $k$ and $B$ is the set of products of length $\ell$.

See [Planning and learning in permutation groups](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Ilan-Shimshoni/publication/3501931_Planning_and_learning_in_permutation_groups/links/54d3694d0cf28e0697282ac9/Planning-and-learning-in-permutation-groups.pdf) for details and variations which use less space but more time.  The rubik's cube solver of Mike Reid is also of interest: [http://www.cflmath.com/~reid/Rubik/optimal_solver.html](http://www.cflmath.com/%7Ereid/Rubik/optimal_solver.html) .

Comment: The factorization of $g$ is of unknown length unless there's an easy way to discern that from maybe the inversion list from the identity, it may not be helpful.

Comment: Details, including what to do if $g$ is of unknown length, are given in the reference I gave.  Basically, consider all possible lengths in increasing order.

Comment: I'm reading through that piece-by-piece. This is the best lead I've had the past three or four times I've asked it. The idea of memoizing patterns and exhausting this way SEEMS like it would reduce time complexity significantly. I can't figure out what the time complexity of naive enumeration is since I don't know by what factor length it would be guaranteed to find the element.